# Inactive "Add Page" in Facebook App settings

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I created a new Facebook App (✓).

Our fan FB page has a new category "App page" (✓).

But I see our fan page disabled when I set it as a App page in App settings. Below I attach a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot from developers.facebook.com]

What I've done bad, why our page is disabled? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably raise a support ticket with facebook for this.

Comment: Does the page name match the app name?

Comment: @CBroe: yes, in other way there isn't the page name (I have more pages, but just this one I see here... but inactive).

Comment: Is the page published, has no restrictions, and the page admin is also the app admin?